# Does SSD drive make indexes rebuild and update stats useless with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, solid-state-drive, rebuild, maintenance-plan

Now that SSD is a standard de-facto. Can the maintenance job of rebuilding indexes and updating statistics, using Ola Hallengren https://ola.hallengren.com/ jobs for instance, be done only on demand instead of regularly such as on weekly basis with Microsoft SQL Server 2017 or lower?

If it is still required, what would be the threshold of the database size to decide when it is necessary ?

Comment: Simply because your hardware is better (not everyone's is - SSD is far from the "standard de-facto") doesn't mean you shouldn't optimize indexes and statistics.  This will still cause additional wear and tear on your drives, and you may still take a speed hit by not doing so (less so than a conventional drive, but it may still be noticeable depending on the query)

Comment: Well it's true that as SSD is as not as cheap os rotational disk so depending on requirements not everybody is using SSD for their database, but there is a lot of cases with new SAN using full SSD or having cache in SSD that it made me think it was getty more standard to have SSD for a database. Do you have factual examples where it will be noticeable for a bad query ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69504617/is-sql-server-affected-by-a-fragmented-index-on-ssd-storage