# Is SQL Server affected by a fragmented index on SSD storage

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Is SQL Server affected by a fragmented index on a SSD storage.
I understand why the fragmentation is an issue for an HDD, but I can't understand how a fragmented index on an SSD will affect database performance. Please help me understand this.

Comment: Are you talking about fragmentation of the index itself? Or fragmentation of the drive? They are very different.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, I didn't knew they were different, thanks for that. I was talking on fragmentation on the index and how it affects performance on different storages SSD vs HDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of disk fragmentation, SSD's are not affected to the same extent that physical spindle drives were.

As @Dale K noted,  fragmentation of an index is different to the fragmentation of the physical drive.

A heavily fragmented index uses more data pages (it's not uncommon for a 98%+ fragmented index to have as many fragment pages as pages). This makes the index larger and can affect query plan choice.

Another issue related to fragmented indexes on larger row count tables, is that if you do not have a regular statistics refresh occurring, the fragmented indexes will also have stale statistics, which can be a much more severe performance killer, since inappropriate, poorly performing query plans might be selected.

Comment: I understand now that a fragmented index uses more data pages, so even if ssd is not much affected like hdd, SQL Server has its own fragmentation and therefore it can still result in a performance penalty, this was what I got from you. So as per your answer I assume it is possible to have a fragmented index in a defragmented disk storage and vice versa? Right?

Comment: Correct........

Comment: By "fragment page" do you mean a page that is <100% full due to a page split?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft : yes, I do. Is there another way to interpret that?

Comment: No, I’ve just never heard it called that.

Comment: Thanks guys for the discussion if no more answers are added I'll accept this one has the most complete answer today. Thanks @DaleK for confirming my questions additional question of disk vs index fragmentation